# SVG foreignobject - rotateX and rotateY gives resize issue on chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit

I have defined a div within svg foreignobject and applied transformations.In firefox there are no issues, element resize according to the browser window. 
On chrome and opera, If I applied rotateX or rotateY then div does not resize according to browser window size. div stays same when resize the browser window. I wanted to resize the div correctly on chrome and opera also.

```css
    .trnsclass{
        transform:translateX(100px) rotateX(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100px) rotateX(30deg); 
    }
```

```html
<svg id="svg3847" viewBox="0 0 1600 700" width="100%">
   <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="800" height="700" id="pic">
    <div class="trnsclass" style="position: absolute;background-color:grey;width:200px;height:200px;" >
   </div>
   </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/nuwandharshana1/pen/zyLEwd)

Comment: rotateX applied to the element as expected. but if you resize the chrome browser it will not resize the element according to browser window size. that is the issue. you can try my code pen example.

Comment: You can report [Chrome bugs here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. I will report it.

Comment: In your codepen example, change `rotateX(30deg)` to `rotate(30deg)` and all seems well--the element shrinks as I resize the window. Best I can tell, `rotateX` isn't working in chrome.

Comment: If we use Inspect element option, the actual element got resized as expected but is stays invisible. is there any workaround to make it visible and remove previously rendered element.